# Double fronted adverbials with the same meaning

Tags: adverbs, adverbials, fronting

For me, double fronted adverbials make sense and sound fine when they have different meanings or tones, for example:

> Slowly, without enthusiasm, he picked up the board and...

But in some texts I've noticed the writer using two fronted adverbials with practically the same meaning. As an example:

> Apparently, so they said, everything in this world was...

It sounds strange to me, but I wonder if this is some writing method I'm not familiar with, since English isn't my first language? Maybe a way to accentuate?

Comment: I actually don't think *apparently* and *so they said* have exactly the same meaning. If it were *Apparently, it looked as if*, then there really would be redundancy.

Comment: @PeterShor maybe in some context they don't, but is "they" refers to just "all people", the meanings seem very close to me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, there is a word for this in grammar: **Asyndetic Coordination.**

> an asyndetic coordination is a type of coordination in which no coordinating conjunction is present between the conjuncts.

*Quickly, resolutely, he strode into the bank.*

No coordinator is present here, but the conjoins are still coordinated.

And according to "Thoughts.co" (Richard Nordquist):

> Asyndeton is a rhetorical term for a writing style that omits conjunctions between words, phrases, or clauses... According to Edward Corbett and Robert Connors, **"The principal effect of asyndeton is to produce a hurried rhythm in the sentence.**"(Classical Rhetoric for the Modern Student, 1999). [Bolding mine]

*Also please note that the words don't have to have the same meaning (as Peter Shor has pointed out.)*